# How to overlay the left sidebar and push the other components to right?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I am making this project, to show NBA data(which is fetched from an API). 
I am trying to replicate this design: https://dribbble.com/shots/16364085-Wallet-Dashboard-Design/attachments/9138740?mode=media 
The main problem I am facing is to overlay the left sidebar over the main box and push the components slightly to the right. Any suggestions on how to do it?
API I am using: https://www.balldontlie.io/#get-all-teams 
github of my project (as there are many components) :https://github.com/TanjimAnim/NBA
I have used ChakraUI and recharts for designing components and showing the chart.

// my App.js file

```
import { Box, ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar";
import RecentMatches from "./components/recent";
import SearchBar from "./components/topbar";
import RenderLineChart from "./components/chart";
import HighestPoints from "./components/table";
import PlayerCard from "./components/cardcomponents";
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Sidebar />
      <Box display='flex' flexDir='column' justifyContent='center'>
        <Box
          w={[700, 800, 900]}
          border='1px'
          boxShadow='md'
          p={5}
          borderRadius={20}
          bg='white'
          borderColor='gray.400'
          mx='auto'
        >
          <SearchBar />
          <PlayerCard />
          <Box
            display='flex'
            justifyContent='space-between'
            alignItems='center'
          >
            <Box>
              <RenderLineChart />
              <RecentMatches />
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <HighestPoints />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//sidebar.js file

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ProSidebar,
  SidebarHeader,
  SidebarFooter,
  SidebarContent,
} from "react-pro-sidebar";
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <ProSidebar>
      <SidebarHeader>My NBA Profile</SidebarHeader>
      <SidebarContent>Dashboard</SidebarContent>
      <SidebarContent>Dashboard</SidebarContent>
      <SidebarContent>Dashboard</SidebarContent>
      <SidebarFooter>
        {/**
         *  You can add a footer for the sidebar ex: copyright
         */}
      </SidebarFooter>
    </ProSidebar>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i handle sidebars (Responsive and RTL compatible and multi-language) using `chakra-ui`

The layout:

```
import {
    Box,
    Drawer,
    DrawerBody,
    DrawerCloseButton,
    DrawerContent,
    DrawerFooter,
    DrawerHeader,
    DrawerOverlay,
    Grid,
    GridItem,
    useBreakpointValue,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactElement, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { SideBarSizeContext } from "../../contexts";
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar";
import { useTheme } from "@chakra-ui/system";

export default function ProjectLayout({ children }: any): ReactElement {
    const { direction } = useTheme();
    const { sidebarSize, setSidebarSize } = useContext(SideBarSizeContext);
    const isMobile = useBreakpointValue({ base: true, md: false });
    useEffect(() => {
        isMobile && setSidebarSize("hide");
    }, [isMobile, setSidebarSize]);
    return (
        <Grid
            templateColumns={{ base: "auto", md: "min-content auto" }}
            css={{ transition: "2s" }}
        >
            {!isMobile ? (
                <GridItem minH="100vh" bg="facebook.500" color="white">
                    {sidebarSize !== "hide" && (
                        <Box paddingBlockStart="1.5">
                            {/* <Flex h="3rem">Logo</Flex> */}
                            <Sidebar sidbarWidth={sidebarSize} />
                        </Box>
                    )}
                </GridItem>
            ) : (
                <Drawer
                    isOpen={sidebarSize !== "hide"}
                    onClose={() => setSidebarSize("hide")}
                    colorScheme="facebook"
                    size="xs"
                    placement={direction === "ltr" ? "left" : "right"}
                >
                    <DrawerOverlay />
                    <DrawerContent width="2.5" dir={direction}>
                        <DrawerCloseButton onClick={() => setSidebarSize("hide")} />
                        <DrawerHeader>Drawer heading text</DrawerHeader>
                        <DrawerBody p="0">
                            <Sidebar sidbarWidth="open-wide" />
                        </DrawerBody>
                        <DrawerFooter></DrawerFooter>
                    </DrawerContent>
                </Drawer>
            )}
            <GridItem>
                <Box bg="gray.100" h="100%">
                    {children}
                </Box>
            </GridItem>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

The context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface LangCTX {
    locale: string;
    changeLocale: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}
export const LanguageContext = createContext({} as LangCTX);

interface SideBarSizeCTX {
    sidebarSize: "compact" | "open-wide" | "hide";
    setSidebarSize: React.Dispatch<
        React.SetStateAction<"compact" | "open-wide" | "hide">
    >;
}
export const SideBarSizeContext = createContext({} as SideBarSizeCTX);
```

The sidebar:

```
import { Flex, List, ListIcon, ListItem, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import { HiOutlineCube, HiOutlineServer } from "react-icons/hi";
import { RiScales3Line, RiKeyLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { GiFirewall } from "react-icons/gi";
import { FaNetworkWired } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BiNetworkChart } from "react-icons/bi";
import { Link as ReactRouterLink, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

interface Props {
    sidbarWidth: "compact" | "open-wide" | "hide";
}

export default function Sidebar({ sidbarWidth }: Props): ReactElement {
    const { id }: any = useParams();
    return (
        <Flex w="100%" justifyContent="flex-start" alignItems="center">
            <List spacing={3} colorScheme="facebook">
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/servers`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="servers"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={HiOutlineServer} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage id="Sidebar.Servers" defaultMessage="Servers" />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/volumes`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="volumes"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={HiOutlineCube} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage id="Sidebar.Volumes" defaultMessage="Volumes" />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/loadbalancer`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="loadbalancer"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={RiScales3Line} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="Sidebar.LoadBalancers"
                                defaultMessage="Load Balancers"
                            />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/floatingips`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="floatingips"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={BiNetworkChart} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="Sidebar.FloatingIps"
                                defaultMessage="Floating IP s"
                            />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/networks`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="networks"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={FaNetworkWired} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="Sidebar.Networks"
                                defaultMessage="Networks"
                            />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/firewalls`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="firewalls"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={GiFirewall} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="Sidebar.FireWalls"
                                defaultMessage="Firewalls"
                            />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem
                    as={ReactRouterLink}
                    to={`/project/${id}/security`}
                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                    alignItems="center"
                    display="flex"
                    flexDirection={sidbarWidth === "open-wide" ? "row" : "column"}
                    gridGap={2}
                    title="security"
                    p="2.5"
                >
                    <ListIcon m={0} p={0} as={RiKeyLine} w={6} h={6} />
                    {sidbarWidth === "open-wide" && (
                        <Text fontSize="xs" textAlign="center" whiteSpace="nowrap">
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="Sidebar.Security"
                                defaultMessage="Security"
                            />
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </Flex>
    );
}
```

The language provider for App.js:

```
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import { LanguageContext } from "../contexts";

import fa from "../lang/fa.json";
import ar from "../lang/ar.json";
import en from "../lang/en.json";

export default function LanguageProvider({ children }: any): ReactElement {
    const [locale, setLocale] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("@myapp/locale") || navigator.language || "en",
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        locale && localStorage.setItem("@myapp/locale", locale);
    }, [locale]);
    const messages: any = {
        fa: fa,
        ar: ar,
        en: en,
    };
    const direction = ["fa", "ar"].includes(locale) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
    const extendedTheme: any = { direction };
    ["fa", "ar"].includes(locale) &&
        (extendedTheme.fonts = { heading: "Vazir", body: "Vazir" });
    const theme = extendTheme({
        ...extendedTheme,
        components: {
            Link: { baseStyle: { _focus: { boxShadow: "none" } } },
            Button: { baseStyle: { _focus: { boxShadow: "none" } } },
        },
    });

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ locale, changeLocale: setLocale }}>
            <IntlProvider
                defaultLocale="en"
                locale={locale}
                messages={messages[locale]}
            >
                <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                    <div dir={direction}>{children}</div>
                </ChakraProvider>
            </IntlProvider>
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

AppBar > Toggle SideBar size button: (hide, compact, open-wide):

```
import { Flex, IconButton, useBreakpointValue } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { MdExitToApp, MdMenu } from "react-icons/md";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import LanguageSwitcher from "./LanguageSwitcher";

interface Props {
    setSideBarSize: Function;
}

export default function AppBar({ setSideBarSize }: Props): ReactElement {
    const history = useHistory();
    const variant = useBreakpointValue({
        base: () =>
            setSideBarSize((prev: "compact" | "open-wide" | "hide") => {
                return prev === "hide" ? "open-wide" : "hide";
            }),
        md: () =>
            setSideBarSize((prev: "compact" | "open-wide" | "hide") => {
                if (prev === "hide") return "open-wide";
                if (prev === "compact") return "hide";
                return "compact";
            }),
    });
    return (
        <Flex
            bg="facebook.400"
            color="white"
            w="100%"
            h="3rem"
            alignItems="center"
            paddingInline="0.3rem"
            justifyContent="space-between"
        >
            <Flex alignItems="center">
                <IconButton
                    variant="unstyled"
                    aria-label="Menu"
                    icon={<MdMenu />}
                    display="flex"
                    alignItems="center"
                    fontSize={24}
                    cursor="pointer"
                    onClick={variant}
                />
                My Panel
            </Flex>
            <Flex>
                <LanguageSwitcher />
                <IconButton
                    variant="unstyled"
                    icon={<MdExitToApp />}
                    fontSize={24}
                    aria-label="Logout"
                    display="flex"
                    alignItems="center"
                    onClick={() => {
                        
                    }}
                />
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hate to say this but what is the JS equivalent of this?

Comment: @tanjimanim just remove types and interfaces